# UWP - Center Text Vertically in TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

So there is an existing [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491649/text-vertical-alignment-in-wpf-textblock) which states that in order to vertically align text, you need to wrap in a border.  However, I tried this, and instead of aligning vertically, the TextBlock went in a corner, still vertically aligned to the top.  I don't know if this has something to do with the differences of WPF and UWP, but no matter, it didn't work.  My TextBlock is defined as follows:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Margin="855,226,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="150" Width="150" FontFamily="DOCK11" 
     TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Sample Text..."/>`
```

With the given dimensions, would it be possible to vertically align my TextBlock's text?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textalignment(v=vs.110).aspx) `TextBlock.TextAlignment`

> Gets or sets a value that indicates the horizontal alignment of text content.

To achieve your goal you indeed should wrap `TextBlock` with a `Border` and set it's `VerticalAlignment` to `Center`.

```
    <Border Height="150" 
            Width="150"
            Margin="855,226,0,0">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   FontFamily="DOCK11"
                   TextAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Padding="0" 
                   Text="Sample Text..."/>
   </Border>
```

Comment: For some reason, when I do this, the TextBlock goes off screen, and I can't even find it.

Comment: It goes off the screen because of `Padding` value you set. If it's a leftover from your experiments, just remove it at all.

Comment: My padding is set to 0 all the way.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Margin`

Comment: The margin is set to 0 as well.  I have no idea what's going on!

Comment: Then you should post an updated code. In your original example you had `Margin="855,226,0,0"`

Comment: `<Border Height="150" 
            Width="150"
            Margin="855,165,495,685">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="DOCK11" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Sample Text..." Height="150" Width="150"/>
        </Border>`

Comment: You said `Margin` is set to `0`, but look at `Border` `Margin`, it's `"855,165,495,685"`!

Comment: Oh!  I thought you meant the margin for the TextBlock.

Comment: Now that you wrap the `TextBlock` into `Border`, some dimention properties moved from `TextBlock` to `Border`. Pay more close attention to my answer, `TextBlock` doesn't have `Width` and `Height` anymore, `Border` does.

Comment: Fixed the margin, however, I still cannot see it.

Comment: I removed the width and the height, and still cannot see it

Comment: The problem might be somewhere up in the view layout. If you set `Background` property of the `Border`, will you be able to see it. If not - it's not a `TextBlock` problem.

Comment: For some reason, the margin was added back automatically, however, now the textblock is way out of position.  **Edit**: There is no background

Comment: Notice that you still have `VerticalAlignment` of `TextBlock` set to `Top` despite of `Center` value in the answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Visual Studio likes changing things itself from time to time.  Thanks for that! Final Code: `<Border Height="150" Margin="1262,163,-1262,687" >
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="DOCK11" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Sample Text..."/>
        </Border>`

Comment: Even though `Margin` values seem odd to me, I'm glad it worked in the end.

Comment: The margin on the border moved the text from the top left corner to where I wanted it.  Without it, it defaulted to the corner.

Comment: But that means your UI is not scalable and `TextBlock` is not truly centered vertically.

Comment: It seems centered to me.  I mean in the sense that I have my border placed on a rectangle with the dimensions of 150x150, and the text is centered vertically in that rectangle

Comment: @Orion31: Not Visual Studio is changing the Margin. I guess you are moving the TextBox with the mouse to you wanted location.